# How to test connection between containers?

Tags: docker, flask

I have an application in Flask, it connects to a tensorflow serving model (this model is in a docker container). Everything works fine locally, but I wanted to serve my Flask application in a container and when I test I get errors, this is:

[image: error]

I think there is a connection problem between the containers, I am new to this topic, please someone who can help me.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: I think first you have to create a Docker Network and then start the TensorFlow serving model into this newly created docker network, note the IP of this container, and then add IP as request into an application container (using environment variable). Make sure your application container also should be in the same docker network.